# Why and how mongoose save in mongodb with ISODate but when retrieve this variable is in local time? (node)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

just wondering why and how when I save some date() in mongoose model:

```
  renovate: {
    type: Date
  }
```

it is storage in mongodb as:

```
ISODate("2020-04-12T11:54:54.568Z"
```

but if I fetch this data into my front end looks like current (correct) time?

```
Sun Apr 12 2020 13:54:54 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can only store times in UTC. Mongoose appears to translate UTC timestamps into local time, presumably for convenience.